# How to use a for loop to filter quantiles of many columns individually

Tags: r, for-loop, filter

I have a timeseries with about 100 dates, 50 entities per date (so 5,000 rows) and 50 columns (all are different variables). How can I filter each column in the data frame, per unique date, to keep the top 1/3 of values for each column on each date. Then get the average Return for that group for that date. I want a "High" subset for each column and then an average returns of that "High" subset for that date. Thank you.

My data is organized as follows but the numbers in each column are random and vary like they do in column "a" (this is a sample, the real data has many more columns and many more rows):

```
Date   Return   a     b     c    d     e      f... ...z
2/1/19   5      75   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19   4      27   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19   7      88   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19   2      55   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/2/19   7      69   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/2/19   8      23   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19   2      34   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19   3      56   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19   4      62   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19   4      43   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19   4      26   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/4/19   6      67   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/4/19   1      78   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/5/19   4      75   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19   5      99   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19   4      72   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19   4      45   43     67   85    72     56     92
```

I am trying to filter data into quantiles. I have a code that works for filtering into quantiles for one measure. However I want filtered results for many measures individually (i.e. I want a “high” group for a ton of columns).

The code that I have that works for one measure is as follows.

Columns are date, identity, and a a is the indicator I want to sort on

```
High = df %>%
    group_by(df.date) %>% 
    filter(a > quantile(a, .666)) %>%
    summarise(high_return = sum(df.return) / length(df.identity)
```

Now I want to loop this for when I have many indicators to sort on individually (I.e. I do not want to sort within one another, I want each sorted separately and the results to be broken out by indicator)

I want the output of the loop to be a new data frame with the following format (where a_Return is the average return of the top 1/3 of the original a's on a given date):

```
Date       a_Return    b_Return    c_Return
2/1/19       6.            7           3
2/3/19       4.            2           5
2/4/19       2.            4           6
```

I have tried the code below without it working:

```
Indicators <- c(“a”, “b”, “c”)

for(i in 1:length(Indicators)){
     High = df %>%
        group_by(df.date) %>% 
        filter(High[[I]] > quantile(High[[i]], .666)) %>%
        summarise(g = sum(df.return) / length(df.identity)}
```

With this attempt I get the error: "Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 20, not 4719.

I also tried:

```
High %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    filter_at(vars(Indicators[i]), any_vars(. > quantile (., .666)))%>%
    summarise(!!Indicators[I] := sum(Return) / n())
```

but with that code I get the error "Strings must match column names. Unknown Columns: NA"

I want High to turn up with a date column and then a column for each a, b, and c.

Comment: `R` is case-sensitive.  Are you using `group_by` `filter`, `summarise` from `dplyr` instead of `Group_by/Filter/Summarize` from some other packages

Comment: There is `filter_at` so, you can specify `%>% filter_at(vars(Indicators[i]), `  Also, in `R`, it is not dot syntax and the column name is only needed, i.e. `df %>% group_by(date) %>% filter_at(vars(indicators[i]), any_vars(. > quantile(., 666))) %>% summarise(!! indicators[i] := sum(return)/n())`

Comment: Thank you for be response. Yes I know it is case sensitive. My computer was just auto capitalizing

Comment: I tried the code above but got the message “error: strings much match column names. Unknown columns: NA”

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to reflect the code you are actually running. (Both your capitalization and quotes seem to be altered.... maybe more?) Otherwise it will be difficult to tell where your problems really are.

Comment: Also,  it really helps if your code was created as a [reprex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/), as we can't really help if we can't run the code ourselves.

Comment: @Gregor I have updated the code to reflect exact specifications. Thank you.